# Meaning of "it's not even close" in this context?

Tags: meaning

In some dialog, I often see something like this:

> Player A is voted as the toughest to play against and it's not even close.

What does "it's not even close" mean in this context? Does that mean Player A is so tough that the second place is not even close to him?

Answer (score 2):

The *it's not even close* refers to the vote.

> Player A is voted as the toughest to play against an it (the vote) is not even close (meaning the second place is far behind).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would take that to mean he is the toughest by a large margin.  "Won by a landslide," so to speak.